# How can I prevent Keynote from storing files in iCloud?

Tags: macos, keynote

I am running Sierra, but I am sure the problem is as bad, or worse, in High Sierra.

I don't want to store files in iCloud, unless I decide to. But now, when I go to save a new file in Keynote, I don't even get a dialogue box: it is automatically put into iCloud, and I have to manually save it elsewhere.  I have thought about turning iCloud off, but I don't mind having system prefs saving stuff there - just not my voluminous workfiles that I share via DropBox instead.
How do I stop this happening?

Comment: Where are you saving the keynote file? And how do you save it to Dropbox?

Comment: I don't use it myself so I am unsure but I believe that saving files automatically to iCloud is a feature of iCloud drive. Can you turn that off?

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences > iCloud > iCloud Drive and click on the Options... button.

In the Documents section, uncheck the Keynote.app (and any other app you don't want) to stop it from saving in iCloud:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting iCloud options only **hides** the files in Apple finder, they will still, by default be saved to iCloud. You can test this by creating and saving a new document while keynote is unticked.
If you then go back into in iCloud options and tick keynote so it is ON again  you will be able to see that document in Finder. The only way to avoid this is to either completely disable iCloud or only use non-Apple apps.